# Connecting a Java Server with a Python Client

Tags: java, python, client-server, python-sockets

So here's the thing, I have a basic java server that sends back to the client what ever it receives from it. The client is written in python. I'm able to make the first connection as in the server sends the client a message confirming the connection. But when I want the client to send the server something is does nothing. I'm not sure if the problem with the client not sending or the server not receiving.

Here's the code for the server:

```
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    try ( 
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        PrintWriter outs =
            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    ) {

        String inputLine, outputLine;


        outputLine = "Hello socket, I'm server";
        outs.println(outputLine);
        outs.println("I' connected");
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
             outputLine = inputLine;
            outs.println(outputLine);
            if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
            + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}  }
```

and here's the client :

```
import socket

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8080

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
print (socket.getaddrinfo(HOST,PORT))
buffer_size = 100

while True :  
    data = sock.recv(buffer_size)     
    print ('you recieved :' , data)
    test = input('send here\n')     
    sock.sendall(bytes(test, 'utf-8'))
    print ('you sent : ' , test)
```

Comment: would using `RESTful` for Java API and using `requests` for python client not be the simple way?

Comment: I don't know. But is it possible for you to explain what exactly I went wrong with this code?

Comment: I suspect the `\n` is destroyed somehow. But I am not familiar with Python.

Comment: Just looked up `input` - so your prompt contains a `\n` but does the result from input? Try adding a `\n` to test before sending.

Comment: You were right. @Fildor . I did that and it worked thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Python client:
Your prompt contains a `\n` but the result from input does not? Try adding a `\n` to `test` before sending.